# how to use Anchor tag instead of LinkButton and use cs file function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

My aspx code is like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="a" runat="server" onitemcommand="functioncommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="Lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ENG")%>' CommandName="cmdname"></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:Label ID="LblS" runat="server" Text=' <%#Eval("ENG")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="LblKey" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("KeywordENG") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It's working fine.. and it will call this function in my cs file:

```
protected void functioncommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "mycommand")
    {
        SId = int.Parse((((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Lblid")).Text));
        Keyword = (((Label)e.Item.FindControl("LblKey")).Text);
        string SName = (((Label)e.Item.FindControl("LblS")).Text);
        Session["sid"] = SId;
        Response.Redirect("/abc/");
    }
}
```

It will then store value to session and redirect to another page.

Problem is: I want to use anchor tag (`<a>`) instead of that link button and call that function from anchor tag, but I don't know how to do this.
 or just call javascript function and pass this value and redirect from their.. i will add link in that tag but i dont want to use that link but use function to store value to session and than redirect... thank you for help....

Comment: If you use an anchor tag `<a>` you cant fire oncommand method, the anchor link redirects the user directly from browser (does not come back to server). Can you expand your question a bit or maybe explain why you need an anchor tag?

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply.. actually i want anchor tag because i want to display link when i hover mouse on that at bottom left of browser status.. i want to store that data in session variable any how and than redirect... no need of command if we can do from other way..

Comment: i need to use anchor tag and use want to call onclick function to that cs function or just simple javascript function.. but it should work same as working now.. like store value to session and redirect

Comment: Ok, a not so fancy but quick workaround is to maintain your linkbutton and set display:none to it. Then add your anchor tag (this will be visible) and capture its click from javascript (or jquery if you may), and instead of follow its href, fire the linkbutton click (which does the postback and the following code gets executed).

Comment: A best cleaner approach is to remove the linkbutton, add anchor tag, and from javascript or jquery capture its click and make a post to server side. Cant do it for you right now, I hope the comments help you.

Comment: ok, understood your comment to click on linkbutton from javascript code.. I m new to asp.net so i dont know much about this repeater thing.. so can you tell me haow can i click on perticular link button from which link was clicked... thank you so much